# Drawer flip animation (Google Photos, Play Store etc.)

Tags: android, android-animation, drawertoggle

The all new hamburger-flip-animation for the drawer button:

[image]

How to do this in Android L? (or lower sdk)

Answer (score 2):

It is in the v7 support library. Probably better using support library APIs rather than third party ones. This answer does a great job of explaining it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26447144/1839500

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/markushi/android-ui

I found this. Maybe it will help me. I will try to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

A Good one for me was, Its not image based. Its based on Drawable

https://github.com/ChrisRenke/DrawerArrowDrawable