# Android ViewDrawer homebutton

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a ViewDrawer with an support-lib actionbaractivity.
My layout looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/drawer_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        layout="@layout/include_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And the activity looks something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends BaseSimpleActivity {
    public static final String FRAGMENT_TAG = "content";
    protected DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    protected ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    protected ListView mDrawerList;
    protected ViewGroup mDrawerView;
    protected View mDrawerBtnSettings;
    private Handler mHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { ... }



    protected void initViews(String title, Fragment fragment) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base_secondary);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, fragment, FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
        initDrawer();
        initActionBar();
    }

    protected void setTitle(String title) {
        super.setTitle(title);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }

    private void initActionBar() {
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP);
        //actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar);

        TextView title = (TextView) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.actionBarTitle);
        title.setText(getTitleResId());
        title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START)) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                } else {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
                }
            }
        });
        refreshActionBar();
    }

    public abstract String getTitleResId();

    private void initDrawer() {
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_container);
        mDrawerView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.drawer_view);

        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new DrawerListAdapter(this));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        mDrawerToggle = createDrawerToggle();
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        mDrawerBtnSettings = findViewById(R.id.drawer_settings);

        refreshDrawer();
    }

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle createDrawerToggle() {
        return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        refreshActionBar();

        int size = menu.size();
        mMenuItemIds = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            mMenuItemIds[i] = menu.getItem(i).getItemId();
        }

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    protected boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerView);
    }

    /**
     * Update the title and invalidate the options menu
     */
    protected void refreshActionBar() {
        if (isDrawerOpen()) {
            setActionBarItemsAlpha(0);
        } else {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getTitle());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update the selected item.
     */
    protected void refreshDrawer() {
        Navigation id = Navigation.getId(this);
        if(id != null) {
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(id.ordinal(), true);
        }
    }

    protected void onDrawerItemClick(int which) {
        // Override if subclass needs to listen for Drawer click events
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectDrawerItem(position);
        }
    }

    protected void selectDrawerItem(final int which) {
        Navigation id = Navigation.getId(this);
        if (id != null && which == id.ordinal()) {
            return;
        }

        onDrawerItemClick(which);
        mPendingLaunch = DrawerUtils.buildLaunchRunnable(this, which);

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerView);
    }
}
```

But as you can see on the screenshot below the icon for the drawer is rendered on some devices and on others its not rendered at all. When i check in android monitor the layout has a width of zero. Any clues on whats going on?

[image: Failing drawer]

Comment: post `R.layout.action_bar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using v21 of AppCompat, you need to use [android.support.**v7**.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) rather than the deprecated v4 version you are using.

Comment: Thank you. Next step would be to implement toolbar in order to be able to change the drawable for the drawer icon. Pity that one cannot do it without toolbar

Comment: You sure? Styling the drawer icon if done from your theme certainly doesn't require the use of a Toolbar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26440502/1676363