# Change color of navigation drawer button (back button)?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

In my app I use action bar and navigation drawer. There's a button in the action bar for opening and closing navigation drawer. I'd like to change its color to red. How do I do that?

[image]

Comment: change the main color https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette

Comment: You can change the drawable image direcly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816418/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-actionbars-up-arrow

Comment: Thanks, Hugo Gresse. I can't believe it was this simple :)

Answer (score 5):

solved on this [Appcombat v7 Toolbar with drawer changing colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27424023/appcombat-v7-toolbar-with-drawer-changing-colors),
do the following in your theme style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">@color/your_red_color</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your app main **color** following **Material Theme** : 
([official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette))

*res/values/colors.xml*

```
<resources>
  <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Another way is to generate the icon on your own : [Toolbar Navigation Hamburger Icon missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28071763/toolbar-navigation-hamburger-icon-missing)