# How to set DrawerArrowToogle (from appcompat v7) background?

Tags: android, drawertoggle

I want to set DrawerArrowToogle background color, when it is in pressed state.  I found the styling for the Drawer, but it has no "background" attribute.

```
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle" parent="">
   <item name="color">?android:attr/textColorSecondary</item>
   <item name="thickness">2dp</item>
   <item name="barSize">18dp</item>
   <item name="gapBetweenBars">3dp</item>
   <item name="topBottomBarArrowSize">11.31dp</item>
   <item name="middleBarArrowSize">16dp</item>
   <item name="drawableSize">24dp</item>
   <item name="spinBars">true</item>
</style>
```

I also tried to set `android:selectableItemBackground`, but it didn't help.

So, how to set background for DrawerArrowToogle (from latest support lib)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26439572/how-to-style-the-drawerarrowtoggle-from-android-appcompat-v7-21-library) post.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
   <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/MyDrawerArrowToggle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDrawerArrowToggle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
  <item name="color">@color/your_color</item>
</style>
```

Comment: `<item name="color">@color/your_color</item>` defines arrow color, not background.

Comment: Well customizing android base styles isn't my strongsuit but could you try adding <item name="background">@drawable/your_background?</item> below the color one? or replace the color one

Answer (score 0):

I shouldn't add "android" to selectableItemBackground because of v7. So it should look like: `<item name="selectableItemBackground">@drawable/toolbar_selectable_background</item>`