# How to style ActionBar back icon from Android appcompat v7 21 library

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I know how to style the DrawerArrowToggle's Back Arrow icon from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26439572/how-to-style-the-drawerarrowtoggle-from-android-appcompat-v7-21-library)

But how to style the Up/Back icon (Arrow) as I don't use DrawerLayout.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ActionBar to change icon with this method.

```
ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_back_arrow);  
ab.show();
```

with this you can set back icon whatever u want.