# CollapsingToolbarLayout arrow color

Tags: android, colors, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm using CollapsingToolbarLayout in my Activity, but I need to change color of back arrow when it is expanded, is there any way to do this?
What I have:

[image]
[image]

What I want to do:

[image]
[image]

Here is my layout, where i put "..." there is layout include with NestedScrollView in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.primebitstudio.swiper.AboutCouponActivity"
    android:layout_marginTop="-1px">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsingToolbarLayoutExpandedTextStyle"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ToolBarStyle">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-24dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/test_image"
                    android:id="@+id/image"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ToolBarStyle" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
...
...
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example how I change my drawer and options icons color when layout is expanded and collapsed:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_layout);
            appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int offset)
                {
                    Drawable upArrow = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.drawer_icon, null);
                    if (offset < -200)
                    {
                        upArrow.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#000000"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);

                        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.option_menu_icon);
                        drawable.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#000000"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                        toolbar.setOverflowIcon(drawable);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        upArrow.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
                        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

                        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.option_menu_icon);
                        drawable.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                        toolbar.setOverflowIcon(drawable);
                    }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation on `ActionBarDrawerToggle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html):

> You can customize the the animated toggle by defining the `drawerArrowStyle` in your ActionBar theme.

The `drawerArrowStyle` attribute lists the following attributes that can be configured:

- `android.support.v7.appcompat:arrowHeadLength`
  The length of the arrow head when formed to make an arrow
- `android.support.v7.appcompat:arrowShaftLength`
  The length of the shaft when formed to make an arrow
- `android.support.v7.appcompat:barLength`
  The length of the bars when they are parallel to each other
- `android.support.v7.appcompat:color`
  The drawing color for the bars
- `android.support.v7.appcompat:drawableSize`
  The total size of the drawable
- `android.support.v7.appcompat:gapBetweenBars`
  The max gap between the bars when they are parallel to each other
- `android.support.v7.appcompat:spinBars`
  Whether bars should rotate or not during transition
- `android.support.v7.appcompat:thickness`
  The thickness (stroke size) for the bar paint

I reckon `android.support.v7.appcompat:color` is what you're after.

---

In order to change the colour at runtime, you have multiple options.

**Option 1**
Get the navigation icon from your `Toolbar` and apply a colour filter to it. For example, to colour the icon red, one could do something like this:

```
Drawable navIcon = mToolbar.getNavigationIcon();
navIcon.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can play around with the various `PorterDuff.Mode` constants to achieve different effects. This approach will also work (and keep working) if you decide to supply your own navigation icon (instead of the default hamburger-turns-arrow-and-vice-versa drawable).

**Option 2**
If you're only interested in colouring the default navigation icon, you can leverage the fact that the navigation icon drawable is a `DrawerArrowDrawable`, which has a `setColor()` method:

```
DrawerArrowDrawable navIcon = (DrawerArrowDrawable) mToolbar.getNavigationIcon();
navIcon.setColor(Color.RED);
```

This second approach may be easier to use if you're planning on animating the colour gradually with the help of i.e. `ObjectAnimator.ofArgb(...)` or `ValueAnimator.ofArgb(...)` (rather than just setting it).

Comment: How do I need to use this? With your answer I founded this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26439572/how-to-style-the-drawerarrowtoggle-from-android-appcompat-v7-21-library) but it makes my toolbar dark and arrow says white what it is collapsed

Comment: @tarasmorskyi: My bad. I misinterpreted your question initially. Styles aren't really meant to be swapped out on-the-fly (at runtime) and hence not very suitable for solving your problem. I've updated my answer with two ways to colour the navigation icon at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        int scrollRange = -1;

        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(final AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            //Initialize the size of the scroll
            if (scrollRange == -1) {
                scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
            }
            //Check if the view is collapsed
            if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                @SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForDrawables") final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);
                upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.black), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
            } else {
                @SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForDrawables") final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);
                upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
            }
        }
    });
```

if you want to change the color of the back-button of the toolbar when using collapsingtoolbarlayout in android.
this is the condition when you want to show different color of back-button when appbarlayout is collapsed or when it is expanded.