# Android Lollipop with Material theme custom Logo doesn't act like DrawerToggle

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

In `Holo` theme adding this

```
 myActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

[image]

I can see the app **logo** (in my case `mm_logo` see below) in left top edge, and this logo acts as drawer toggle button

In `Material` the logo isn't shown

[image]

but if I add

```
myActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

the app icon is shown at the top left edge  (in my case `ic_launcher` see below)

```
 <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:logo="@drawable/mm_logo"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.GreenAppTheme"
            android:largeHeap="true">
```

If I add both these lines

```
myActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
myActionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

The logo is shown also in Material but tend to fill the space leaved by buttons with too high left margin and doesn't act like a drawer toggle button(is a simple static image). Here an example:

[image]

Any idea to configure action bar to show in material design theme the logo `mm_logo` to act like drawer toggle without re-implement a custom `ActionBar` class?

NOTE: The drawer button works in material, what I want is that the drawer toggles also if the users click on the logo not only clicking directly the 3 lines drawer button

Answer (score 2):

You can use the new support library `v7 appcompat library`.

The new `ActionBarDrawerToggle` in support v7 library is updated, which contains the menu-to-arrow animation.

I have answer a familiar question in which I mentioned how to implement this animation with support library.

Here is the link:[How to implement DrawerArrowToggle from Android appcompat v7 21 library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434504/how-to-implement-drawerarrowtoggle-from-android-appcompat-v7-21-library/26447144#26447144)

Comment: The drawer button works in material, what I want is that the drawer toggles also if the users click on the logo not only clicking directly the 3 lines drawer button

Comment: @Silverstorm If you use Toolbar which is added in support.v7.library, you can call the function `setNavigationIcon(int resId)` to set your logo as a navigation icon, so that you can click it as you click the ActionBarDrawerToggle without a custom ActionBar.Hope this can help you.