# How animate Burger to Arrow with Appcompat v7 21, Toolbar and DrawerLayout

Tags: android, toolbar, android-appcompat, drawerlayout, drawertoggle

I am using the android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar with a android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout. It works fine, the Burger icon is shown when the Navigation Drawer is closed, and the Arrow icon is shown when the Drawer is open. 
I want to disable the drawer and animate the Burger icon into Arrow on some event in the app. I have tried to set the lock mode to closed, but the v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle is still showing the Burger and it opens the Drawer.

mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);

Any ideas?
Thanks!

**Update:**

No I can change the state of the icon and I can enable/disable the drawer, but the animations are not working with this approach:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.application_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.string1, R.string.string2) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    //mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle); // not needed
    ...
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if (mDrawerLayout.getDrawerLockMode(GravityCompat.START) == LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED) {
                showDrawer();
            } else {
                handleBackButtonPress(); // On this stage the home button is a <-
            }
    }
    ...
}

private void setDrawerState(boolean isEnabled) {
    if (isEnabled) {
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
        mDrawerToggle.onDrawerStateChanged(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

    } else {
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        mDrawerToggle.onDrawerStateChanged(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
}
```

The drawer comes on the top of the Toolbar.

Answer (score 37):

Have a look here, it describes how you solve it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26447144

The essential part is the following:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think you misunderstand my question. I want to completely disable the navigation drawer (on run-time) and show the arrow icon instead of the burger.

Comment: I have got the same problem any idea ?

Answer (score 29):

I created a small application which had similar functionality

MainActivity

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                drawerLayout,
                toolbar,
                R.string.open,
                R.string.close
        )

        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
            {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                syncState();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
            {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                syncState();
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        //Set the custom toolbar
        if (toolbar != null){
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
}
```

My XML of that Activity

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    >

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_custom"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#457C50"/>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My Custom Toolbar XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark">
    <TextView android:text="U titel"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Theme"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

My Theme Style

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarker</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <color name="primary">#457C50</color>
    <color name="primaryDarker">#580C0C</color>
</resources>
```

My Styles in values-v21

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Ah, I love you. I struggeled to get the damn arrow animation. However, seeing your code I found mine was missing this line:         
drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

Now it works like a charm!

Comment: Is it necessary to extend from ActionBarActivity?