# Toolbar back arrow show as black color on 4.x devices

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I have used Toolbar and used design library.The toolbar navigation icon and back arrow icon display as white on Android 5.0 device.But on Android 4.x devices it display as black color icons.How to diaplay the icons as white color on both Android 5.0 and Android 4.x devices.

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


    final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);

    upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(upArrow);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,toolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name){

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            fab1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            fab1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState(); /* if comment this line white color applied,but only arrow displayed,not display nav icon(three line icon)*/
}


@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

**toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.Title"
    app:elevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    >
```

**values\styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar.Title" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
        <!-- Set proper title size -->
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material_toolbar</item>
        <!-- Set title color -->
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/toolbar_title</item>
</style>
```

**values-v21\styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar.Title" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
        <!-- Set proper title size -->
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material_toolbar</item>
        <!-- Set title color -->
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/toolbar_title</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already post the answer :)

```
    //final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);

    //upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

    //toolbar.setNavigationIcon(upArrow);
```

This is works. Tested on 4.4.2

> I think you have a so many attempts, that have a confusion.

Comment: @Ramprasad did you try remove other commented code? 
It works for me. May be you set color in `*.xml` theme file also?

Comment: @Ramprasad if you change back button color in code will be better you need remove all occurrences in `styles.xml` and `themes.xml`. It may produce conflicts

Comment: I tried by removing app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" on xml file.But not works...

Comment: Also uncomment lines you have mentioned,but not works.Something I done mistake...

Comment: @Ramprasad re-check attentively. on 4.0 also works. Tested now.

Comment: I have updated all my code above.If i remove mDrawerToggle.syncState();  line white color applied,but only arrow displayed,not display nav icon(three line icon).

Comment: I fixed this issue.refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26469738/884079 and removed uparrow drawable code.It works great...tested on 4.2.1 version.