# Android overrride onclick of Toggle Button Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, actionbardrawertoggle, navigation-drawer

I want to change the toggle view of mDrawerToggle to Arrow from Burger icon and locking the sliding listview as well. When this arrow is clicked, I want to launch an activity instead of the listview.

Code:

```
drawer.closeDrawer(drawerListView);
                    drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
                    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
                    mDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26468634/how-animate-burger-to-arrow-with-appcompat-v7-21-toolbar-and-drawerlayout