# Properly handle DrawerLayout animation while navigating through fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation, navigation-drawer

I'm currently struggling with the `DrawerLayout` animation doing weird stuff; The **hamburger icon** is laggy and often switch from hamburger to arrow without animation if I don't put an Handler to delay the `fragment` transaction animation.

So I ended up putting an handler to wait until the hamburger icon perform the animation but it just doesn't feel natural that we need to wait until the drawer close to switch fragment. I'm sure there is a better way to handle this...

**Here is how I do currently:**

```
private void selectProfilFragment() {
    final BackHandledFragment fragment;
    // TODO test this again
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(FragmentUserProfile.USER_FIRST_NAME, user.getFirstname());
    bundle.putString(FragmentUserProfile.USER_LAST_NAME, user.getLastname());
    bundle.putString(FragmentUserProfile.USER_PICTURE, user.getProfilepic());
    bundle.putString(FragmentUserProfile.USER_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
    bundle.putBoolean(FragmentUserProfile.USER_SECURITY, user.getParameters().getSecuritymodule().equals("YES"));
    fragment = new FragmentUserProfile();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerLinear);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left, R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right);
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                    .addToBackStack(fragment.getTagText())
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    }, 300);
}
```

It's still *glitching* a little bit in between the `DrawerLayout` closing and opening fragment transaction animation.

**Here is How I instanciate the drawer:**

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

mDrawerListChild.setAdapter(new DrawerListAdapter(this, R.layout.drawer_layout_item, mPlanTitles));
mDrawerListChild.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

mProfilPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        selectProfilFragment();
    }
});

mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this,
        mDrawerLayout,
        toolbar,
        R.string.drawer_open,
        R.string.drawer_close
) {
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
};
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(mOnBackStackChangedListener);
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: I guess initialization of BackHandledFragment has heavy processing.
Change BackHandledFragment`s `onCreateView` and `onActivityCreated` simple, and delay heavy processing.

Comment: That's not the issue though because it only happens with the Profile Fragment...

Comment: Sorry, I make a mistake. Does the initialization of FragmentUserProfile have  heavy prosessing?

Comment: Even with this, how are we suppose to handle the closing drawer animation THEN swapping fragment? Because, doing both at the same time doesn't feel natural... And yeah maybe FragmentProfil is a little heavy but then again, thats not the question

Comment: I mean even if the processing of the fragment was REALLY quick, I would still need to wait until the Drawer close to perform the fragment swipe animation

Comment: I have similar android app which has NavigationDrawer, but does not have animation of Fragment transition. My app does not skip drawer animation and hamburger icon animation. So if initialization of FragmentProfile is simple, the reason of animation skip is possibly too many animation. I recommend you to check gpu monitor to detect the reason. https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-gpu.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what causing this behavior though I want to draw your attention on few thing.

1. I am not aware which `ActionBarDrawerToggle` class you are using but preferable to use `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` instead of `android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` as it is deprecated.
2. Use `addDrawerListener()` instead of `setDrawerListener()` as it is deprecated.
3. Use [spinBars](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.styleable.html#DrawerArrowToggle_spinBars) and set value `true` to rotate bars during transition.
   e.x. in your **styles.xml** as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434504/how-to-implement-drawerarrowtoggle-from-android-appcompat-v7-21-library/26447144#26447144).
4. In `onDrawerClosed` and `onDrawerOpened` call [syncState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#syncState()). Also call this method on your `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26468634/how-animate-burger-to-arrow-with-appcompat-v7-21-toolbar-and-drawerlayout).

   Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

Heres how you can do it. In the Activity containing fragment setup your drawer.

```
public void setupDrawer(){
 NavigationFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mActionbarToggle = drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer, mDrawerLayout, mToolbar); 
}
```

Now in the NavigationDrawerFragment define your **setUp** method

```
public ActionBarDrawerToggle setUp(int navigation_drawer, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar mToolbar) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(navigation_drawer);
        this.mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        //mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, mToolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }
                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }
                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ((MainActivity) mContext).onBackPress();
            }
        });
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        return mDrawerToggle;
    }
```

That's it, your drawer is completely setUp.

Comment: what is isAdded()? I'm not following you, how is that suppose to fix my issue?

Comment: What the hell is a NavigationFragment? This set up method should've never left the activity.

Comment: you have to call the setup() from the activity which contains navigationFragment @EugenPechanec

Comment: My point is there shouldn't ever be a NavigationFragment. You're calling a method of the fragment from inside an activity and that fragment only ever touches views outside of its own scope. Not only is the fragment pointless it also shows bad design.