# how do I properly install support-v7 repo in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Currently my dependencies look like:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile files('libs/volley_1_0_8.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:21.0.2'
compile files('libs/volley.jar')
compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
}
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
  Error:Failed to find: com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2
  Install Repository and sync project
  Open File
  Open in Project Structure dialog
```

It looks like I have everything needed inside the SDK:

[image]

Clicking on "Install Repository and sync project" prompts me to install the support repo rev 9 (which I already have, according to the SDK manager?)
While installing I always get the error

```
 Failed to rename directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\extras\android\m2repository to C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\temp\ExtraPackage.old01.
```

It seems the directory is in use by Android Studio itself.

**The question:** how can I install the v7 support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of the support-v4 is `21.0.0`. There is no such library as `support-v7` - if you mean `appcompat-v7`, then that is also `21.0.0` as per [gradleplease.appspot.com](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/), which is a handy reference for the latest versions of various libraries.

The reason the SDK Manager has the version at 21.0.2 is because other parts of the support library (specifically, the [Multidex support library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#multidex)) was changed since the initial release of version 21.0.0, but that did not change the support-v4 or other parts.

Comment: oh well.. thanks. I'm a bit confused after changing to AS. Could you point me out how to use the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` so it't not deprecated? Could not get it from the answers around here on SO

Comment: You'd want to use the `v7` version of `ActionBarDrawerToggle` per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26434879/1676363)