# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-appcompat

when I import an eclipse project to the AS,an error occurred:

```
E:\studioWorkspace\YTHDBL\yTHDBL\build.gradle
Error:Error:line (25)Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1
Install Repository and sync project
Show in File
open.dependency.in.project.structure
Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
Error:Error:line (24)Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1   
Install Repository and sync project
Show in File
open.dependency.in.project.structure
Show in Project Structure dialog
```

I searched for answers and found this:[how do I properly install support_v7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27048859/how-do-i-properly-install-support-v7-repo-in-android-studio)

Did I set the wrong support library number?,I tried 22.0.0,22.2.0.....,but not worked.

In my sdk manager ,the Android support Repository was installed,reversion 16,and the Android Support Library was already installed,reversion 22.2.1.
The google Repository was installed too.

and this is my build.gradle:

```
 dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':alipay_lib')
    compile project(':sMSSDK')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile files('libs/alipay.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-query.0.25.10.jar')
    compile files('libs/baidumapapi_v3_1_0.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.11.jar')
    compile files('libs/jpush-sdk-release1.7.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/locSDK_4.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/umeng-analytics-v5.5.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/zxing.jar')
}
```

where are the problems?  and now I can't find the "try again" button in AS,how can I try again?

Comment: Have you updated your support library in the android sdk manager?

Comment: click on Install repository in log

Comment: my support library in the sdk manager has updated, is 22.2.1

Comment: "click on Install repository in log", I'm sorry, I can't understand your answer,

Comment: the log was cleared by me just now,  @Jemshit Iskenderov

Comment: check on your `local.properties` file that its `sdk.dir` property is pointing to the correct SDK path (maybe Android Studio is looking for the support library somewhere else).

Answer (score 3):

I opened my android_sdk then updated my Android Support Repository, Android Support Library and Google Repository, so the problem in my Intellij is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I meet the similar error too.But my problem is failed to resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1. I update the Local Maven repository for Support Libraries and Android Support Library in Extra to the newest version.Finally,my problem is over.