# how to change icon of navigation drawer DrawerArrowToggle?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-appcompat

hello i am using `AppCompat v7` for Navigation drawer. i required to change hamburger menu icon with no animation.

[image]

i gone through style of `DrawerArrowToggle` and found this

```
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle" parent="">
        <item name="color">?android:attr/textColorSecondary</item>
        <item name="thickness">2dp</item>
        <item name="barSize">18dp</item>
        <item name="gapBetweenBars">3dp</item>
        <item name="topBottomBarArrowSize">11.31dp</item>
        <item name="middleBarArrowSize">16dp</item>
        <item name="drawableSize">24dp</item>
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    </style>
```

and there is no drawable attribute to set custom icon. so is there way to change icon?

i know we can disable `drawerToggle` and set custom image in toolbar and maintain open and close state.

Comment: You have to use custom ActionBar

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434504/how-to-implement-drawerarrowtoggle-from-android-appcompat-v7-21-library

Comment: Have you used `ActionBarDrawerToggle` method for it? In this method you can change it.

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes.. there is now we have to pass toolbar instead of icon..

Comment: @SanketKachhela Ok. So you can change there using `mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
    R.drawable.logo_menu_top, R.string.app_name,

    R.string.app_name) {`

Comment: bro it's of older version without AppCompat .

Comment: Ok. So you are using third party library

Comment: please read question carefully

Comment: @SanketKachhela Yeah. Okay

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74101/discussion-between-sanket-kachhela-and-piyush-gupta).

Answer (score 1):

I think currently this is not possible if you use **v7** ActionBarDrawerToggle. This class has only a package-local constructor which allows you to change the burger-menu / slider.

Source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.java

```
/**
 * In the future, we can make this constructor public if we want to let developers customize the animation.
 */
<T extends Drawable & DrawerToggle> ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity activity, Toolbar toolbar, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, T slider, @StringRes int openDrawerContentDescRes, @StringRes int closeDrawerContentDescRes) {
    // some code
    if (slider == null) {
        mSlider = new DrawerArrowDrawableToggle(activity,
        mActivityImpl.getActionBarThemedContext());
    } else {
       mSlider = slider;
   }

}
```

As a (bad) workaround I would suggest you to continue using the old **v4** ActionBarDrawerToggle, which allows the customization of the burger icons.

Please notice that you can customize the default animation-slider as described in this SO-comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26447144/2960788

Furthermore you could tint the slider by setting

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">#ccffffff</item>
```

in your toolbar's theme.