# Setting a toolbar click action

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

I wanted to replace the deprecated version of  `android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` so i looked a little and found how to do it : [How to implement DrawerArrowToggle from Android appcompat v7 21 library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434504/how-to-implement-drawerarrowtoggle-from-android-appcompat-v7-21-library)
Except it doesnt work : I get this error `This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor`
And if I change the style the action bar wont be seen.

Comment: Try to set style : Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.

Comment: But i want action bar - i want to set an icon at the action bar to open up the drawer

Comment: Use toolbar instead of action bar