# Android Toolbar occupies full screen

Tags: android

Here's all my relevant code:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("sometitle");
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Styles:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/sunshine_blue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/sunshine_dark_blue</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item> <!-- Remove the default action bar -->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

XML:

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Replace the default action bar -->
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

<!-- The main content view -->
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.***.***.***.MainActivityFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
```

And here's the result:[image]

Comment: Probably need to specify a fixed height rather than use `wrap_content`?

Comment: What if you remove minheight and maxHeight and use a specific size instead of wrap_content ?

Comment: But hardcoded sizes are bad practice right?

Comment: Is this the only XML code you have ? are you not wrapping the code inside another view say, Frame layout or Relative Layout?

Comment: No I am @rogerthatcode .. By the way just for the sake of it I gave the hardcoded sizes a shot and it didn't work inmyth .

Comment: The above code seems to be okay. It will be helpful if you can add more code..

Comment: Can you try and put DrawerLayout and Toolbar inside a Frame Layout ?

Comment: Yup. Took the toolbar outside the drawer layout and wrapped them in a relative layout. Please post it as an answer so that I can accept it..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Possible solution will be to move the Toolbar outside the DrawerLayout and put those two inside a frame layout.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- The main content view -->
        <fragment
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:name="com.***.***.***.MainActivityFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <!-- The navigation drawer -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#111"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <!-- Replace the default action bar -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Just one final thing (sorry about that) my hamburger doesn't spin and animate to a back button though I've set `<item name="spinBars">true</item> ` in my styles

Comment: check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434504/how-to-implement-drawerarrowtoggle-from-android-appcompat-v7-21-library

Comment: That is actually the one that I followed.. I edited the styles in the original question so that you can see the big picture..

Comment: if like this the `toolbar` will cover  a part of `drawerlayout`

Comment: @chinaanihchen The attribute `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` on `DrawerLayout` will make sure the fragment inside will not be covered with `toolbar` as it is setting a padding equal to the height of  `toolbar`

Comment: @ Kushal Sharma. thanks for reply,I want when  the `drawerlayout` showing to cover the `toolbar`,my content which is a `fragment` is match parent without `toolbar `,finally, i set `toolbar` and `FrameLayout` in a `LinearLayout`,  `LinearLayout` and `Listview` in to `DrawerLayout `

Comment: The paddingTop is not respected, replace the FrameLayout with LinearLayout.

Answer (score 12):

The `DrawerLayout` is allowed only 2 children. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html):

> - The main content view (the FrameLayout above) must be
>     the first child in the DrawerLayout because the XML order implies
>     z-ordering and the drawer must be on top of the content.
> - The main
>     content view is set to match the parent view's width and height,
>     because it represents the entire UI when the navigation drawer is
>     hidden.

Try wrapping your `Toolbar` and `fragment` in a `FrameLayout`.

Comment: Thanks.. I already got the answer though.. +1 (I know we're not supposed to make comments like these but I think that rule doesn't make sense, how else are we supposed to appreciate)

Comment: This explained the root cause of the issue rather than just a solution, thanks!