# Changing Hamburger Action bar Icon to Rotating Arrow Not Working, when Opening the Navigation Drawer in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, drawertoggle

I am using Navigation Drawer in my Android application,its Working fine.

i want to add some **Animation** for **Open** and **Close** the **Navigation Drawer**.

Animation:

1.Opening-Navigation Drawer show the **Arrow** ,Hide the **Hamburger**.

2.Closing-Again Show the **Hamburger**, hide the **Arrow**.

while Opening and closing it should be Rotate. i tried some code its not Working.

Please anyone help me to do this.

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

I tried this ,  [link i referred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26447144/4447803)

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;


//for Navigation Bar
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
        ListView listView;
        String[] drawerlist;
        ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerListener;

        private MyAdapter4 myAdapter4;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alerts);




                //navigation initialize
                        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
                        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
                        drawerlist = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawerlist);

                        myAdapter4 = new MyAdapter4(this);
                        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter4);

                        //for navigation click

                        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

                        //Navigation Bar starts

                        drawerListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle
                       (this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, 
                                    R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)
                        {

                            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView)
                            {
                                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                            }

                            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
                            {
                                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                            }
                        };

                            drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerListener);
                            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
                            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            }
```

My navigation drawer Code

Comment: Paste code. Maybe are you missed something.

Comment: Same code works for me, instead of ActionBarActivity i have used AppCompatActivity. Post your activity code...

Comment: i want to import any new library ?

Comment: @SumighoshCharuvil Hi, there is no difference beetwen ActionBarActivity and AppCompatActivity. I have read source code and ActionBarActivity extends AppCompatActivity and it's deprecated and empty.

Comment: @Kumar No you don't need. Paste code of Activity.

Comment: The import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle cannot be resolved this error coming

Comment: Ok, there is the problem with library. If you want i can upload this library and paste link here.

Comment: i have used normal action bar activity, it already imported import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82478/discussion-between-krystian71115-and-kumar).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check below is a sample code for getting Hamburger styled navigation drawer

```
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
    private ArrayList<DrawerItem> drawerItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private DrawerListAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer_list);
    addDrawerItems();

/**Drawer Initialization*/
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle
            (
                    this,
                    drawerLayout,
                    R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                    R.string.navigation_drawer_close
            )
    {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getSupportActionBar().show();
        }
    };
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
}

 private void addDrawerItems() {
    drawerItems.add(new DrawerItem("ALL"));
    drawerItems.add(new DrawerItem("FAVOURITES"));
    drawerItems.add(new DrawerItem("FILTERS"));
    drawerItems.add(new DrawerItem("SETTINGS"));

     DrawerListAdapter adapter = new DrawerListAdapter(this, drawerItems);
            mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
            mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                ///Write your listener here

            }});
        }
}
```

Check the import to know the libraries that i have.

My v7 library version number compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'

UPDATE: Add below to your strings.xml

```
<string name="navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
<string name="navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
```

Comment: this code will Work ? Error in The import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle cannot be resolved

Comment: This is a working code. Update your v7 library to latest.

Comment: Paste this into your strings.xml  
    <string name="navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
    <string name="navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>

Comment: i Have added my Code let me Know What to do?

Comment: i have updated my library V7,it will work as a Rotating Arrow Navigation Drawer?

Comment: I will share you a sample project that i have created for you in a min.

Comment: @Kumar Yes, after update V7 library it should be work.

Comment: @Kumar, krystian71115 is right, you have to update the lib. However test it out the sample.

Comment: @Kumar You have errors in resource files after update in styles. Am i right?

Comment: @Kumar This error occurs when project build target is lower than api 21.

Comment: [2015-07-06 18:10:52 - NewDemo] E:\Workspace3\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:136: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.

Comment: See answer in discussion: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82478/discussion-between-krystian71115-and-kumar

Answer (score 3):

Update your SDK Platform to the newest (The current is API 22) and set project  (appcompat_v7) build target to API 22.