# Android support package for some widgets

Tags: android, android-support-library

I use Android support library **23.0.1**. I want to style `Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar` and `Base.Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle`. What support do I add to enable these widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use a Toolbar. A toolbar is basically a ViewGroup and emulates most (if not more) of the functionalities of the ActionBar.

To include a spinner:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <Spinner
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Reference: http://android-developers.blogspot.cl/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

As for the arrow toggle, take a look at this: [How to implement DrawerArrowToggle from Android appcompat v7 21 library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434504/how-to-implement-drawerarrowtoggle-from-android-appcompat-v7-21-library/26447144#26447144)

Basically you'll need to create this style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

And do some initialization on your onCreate.